# Gradle passing arguments to a plugin task

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have these tasks from [gradle-js-plugin](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin):

```
combineJs {
    source = sourceJs
    dest = file(destDirJs + "/all.js")
}

minifyJs {
    source = combineJs
    dest = file( destDirJs + "/all-min.js")
    closure {
        warningLevel = 'QUIET'
    }
}

gzipJs {
    source = minifyJs
    dest = file(destDirJs + "/all-gzip-min.js")
}
```

My problem is because I´ll have to change the values of sourceJs, and destDirJs multiple times. So I don't want to have a lot of duplicated code.

So I´m trying something like this:

```
task gzipAll {
    sourceJs = ["WebContent/plugin/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js", "WebContent/plugin/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js", "WebContent/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js", "WebContent/js/mandatory/bootstrap-analytics-setup.js"]         
    destDirJs = "WebContent/js/mandatory"
    tasks.combineJs().execute;
    tasks.minifyJs().execute;
    tasks.gzipJs().execute;

    //Here I need to change sourceJs and destDir and call all the task again.
}
```

Actually I was trying a long shot in the dark, and I got the exception:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'sourceJs' on task ':combineJs'.
```

I also tried something like this, but didn't work. Got some exceptions:

```
combineJs(sourceJs, destDirJs) {
    source = $sourceJs
    dest = file($destDirJs + "/all.js")
}
```

Can anyone with more experience help me solve this ? Is it kinda simple right?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have to change those values multiple times?

Comment: Because I cant have 1 JS with ALL of js. I have 1 minified and compressed for mandatory JS (all pages use) and one specific for each page. So i´ll have 2 minified and compress JS for each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested it but since gradle scripts are groovy scripts you should be able to do something like this.

```
['dir1', 'dir2'].eachWithIndex { dir, index ->
    task "combineJs_$index"(type: combineJs) {
        source = dir
        dest = file(destDirJs + "/$index.js")
    }

    task "minifyJs_$index" (type: minifyJs) {
        source = "combineJs_$index"
        dest = file( destDirJs + "/$index-min.js")
        closure {
            warningLevel = 'QUIET'
        }
    }

    task "gzipJs_$index" (type: gzipJs) {
        source = "minifyJs_$index"
        dest = file(destDirJs + "/$index-gzip-min.js")
    }
}
```

Of course you need the correct TaskTypes and you'll probably need the change the input, but this should get you going.